# Expanding $x^x$ to series with $o(x)$ polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have some doubts in finding $x^x$ series. 
 I know that from Taylor theorem I have
$$ f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 + \cdots + \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k + o(x^k) $$

I want to have $o(x)$ polynomials so:
Let $$ f(x) = x^x $$ 
$$ f'(x) = (e^{x\cdot \ln x}) = (\ln x + 1)x^x$$
In use of taylor I should
$$ f(x) = f(0) + \frac{f'(0)(x)}{1!} + o(x) $$
but $f(0)$ is not defined $0^0$. Also $f'(0)$ is not defined...
But I found informations that it should be 
$$  1+ \ln x \cdot x + o(x)$$
I don't know why :-(

Comment: notice that $0^0 =1$

Comment: $x^x$ is not defined for $x<0$ so you can't possibly expand it in a Taylor series about the origin.  However, since $x^x=e^{x\log{x}}$ you can substitute $x\log{x}$ into the Taylor series for $e^x$

Comment: Not every function has a Taylor series (it has to be differntiable arbitrarily many times). $x^x$ is one of those that do not have Taylor expansion around 0 (because it's not differentiable at that point). It has a Taylor expansion around any point $a>0$ though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have written
$$x^x=e^{x\ln{x}}$$
and as the series expansion of $e^x$ converges for all values of $x\in\mathbb{C}$ one can write
$$e^x=\frac{x^0}{0!}+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...$$
$$e^{x\ln{x}}=\frac{(x\ln{x})^0}{0!}+\frac{(x\ln{x})^1}{1!}+\frac{(x\ln{x})^2}{2!}+...$$
$$\therefore x^x=1+x\ln{x}+\frac{x^2\ln^2{x}}{2}+\frac{x^3\ln^3{x}}{6}+...$$

Comment: Yes, that trick really helps me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$ are not defined, one can write$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x=e^{\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\ln x}=e^0=1$$In that case $${f(x)=x^x\sim 1\\f'(x)=x^x(\ln x+1)\sim \ln x+1}$$both when $x\to0^+.$ Here is a plot of the function:[image]